# C array char compare to array int

Tags: c, arrays, char, int, quicksort

I work currently on in place generic Quicksort.
I start with an int array which is randomly generated to do some tests.

The specification of the quiksort is :
`quicksort(void *array,int numberElem,int size, cmp(void*,void*))`

cmp a compare function.

So :
I call the function in my main like :

```
int main(void){
 int myArray= .....randomly;
 quicksort((void *)myArray,100,sizeof(int),cmp)
}
```

Then in my quicksort :

```
quicksort(void *array,int numberElem,int size, cmp(void*,void*)){
char *lArray;
lArray= (char*)array;
}
```

Now the question is :
How I can compare 2 cell (realy int cells) of my char lArray using size ?

I ve been some research and not find answer.
Thanks for ready and sorry if my english was little bad.

Comment: Why do you declare lArray as a char pointer and not an int pointer? Doing so would resolve this quite nicely it seems.

Comment: Yes in this solution i can resolve this problem, but the goal is to do a generic quiksort, for exemple in the future i can give an array of struct to my quicksort.
It's a study exercise.

Comment: And before this exercise i made a quicksort only on int array.
My professor tell me , "now make your quicksort generic, you must use char cast because the size of char (1) can be multiply with other type size.

Comment: You should not use a `(void *)` cast in `quicksort`. 6.3.2.3 "A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type." C and C++ differ in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to multiply size by the index of the element you're accessing (pay attention to `Param1` and `Param2` in the the insertion sort). I took the time to write a fairly lengthy example with insertion sort rather than quicksort: the general structure behind the type genericness is the same but you'll obviously have to apply quicksort rather than selection sort.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int CmpChar(void* Param1, void* Param2) {
    char  P1 = *((char*) Param1);
    char  P2 = *((char*) Param2);
    return P1 < P2;
}

int CmpShort(void* Param1, void* Param2) {
    short  P1 = *((short*) Param1);
    short  P2 = *((short*) Param2);
    return P1 < P2;
}

int CmpInt(void* Param1, void* Param2) {
    int    P1 = *((int*) Param1);
    int    P2 = *((int*) Param2);
    return P1 < P2;
}

int CmpLong(void* Param1, void* Param2) {
    long long P1 = *((long long*) Param1);
    long long P2 = *((long long*) Param2);
    return    P1 < P2;
}

void GenericInsertionSort(void* Array, int Length, int Size, int Cmp(void*, void*)) {
    char* lArray = (char*) Array;
    void* Temp = malloc(Size);
    for (int i = 0; i < (Length - 1); i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        void* Param1 = lArray + Size*j;
        void* Param2 = lArray + Size*(j - 1);
        while (j && Cmp(Param1, Param2)) {
            memcpy(Temp, Param2, Size);
            memcpy(Param2, Param1, Size);
            memcpy(Param1, Temp, Size);
            j--;
            Param1 = ((char*) Param1 - Size);
            Param2 = ((char*) Param2 - Size);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    long long   A1[] = {5, 3, 1, 4, 2};
    int         A2[] = {5, 3, 1, 4, 2};
    short       A3[] = {5, 3, 1, 4, 2};
    char        A4[] = {5, 3, 1, 4, 2};
    GenericInsertionSort(A1, 5, 8, CmpLong);
    GenericInsertionSort(A2, 5, 4, CmpInt);
    GenericInsertionSort(A3, 5, 2, CmpShort);
    GenericInsertionSort(A4, 5, 1, CmpChar);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%llu == %d == %d == %d\n", A1[i], A2[i], A3[i], A4[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and for taking the time to make a complete example.
I think I've understand : 
1)Use char cast in the local context of the sort  for pointing.
2)Use a specific compare function in function of the type passed in parameter.
It's that ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to stress the part about multiplying the element size with the index of the element you're trying to access. That's the actual trick that makes this work.

Comment: I fully understood what you explained to me, and the error came from my comparison function and not from my quicksort, because I was trying to compare integers larger than 128 so the char did not allow a correct comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Quic sort calls your compare function with pointers to the elements to be compared. In your compare function `cmp` (or any othe name you want to use), you first cast these void pointers to the type that they are pointing to, in your case to `int`. Then you compare them:

```
int cmp(void* x1,void* x2)
{
    int *v1= (int *)x1, *v2= (int *)x2;
    return (*v1<*v2);
}
```

or

```
int cmp(void* x1,void* x2)
{
    return (*((int *)x1) < *((int *)x2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not think to change the comparison function according to the type to compare my elements, but thereby what the type to convert my void array on the quicksort ?
For example:

```
quicksort(void *array,int numberElem,int size, cmp(void*,void*)){
**HERE** *lArray;
lArray= (**HERE***)array; 
}
```

Comment: More precisly :
In my int array i have the number 383 at the first index.
When I do :
char *lArray = (char*) array;

And take the 1st element of lArray i have 127, because int and char dont have the same size, but if i compare 127 with other cell of the l tab maybe 127 was lower than this cell but the real number was highter